# displaying image from datatable asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried everything found on google search to display image from datatable to webform. I'm filling the datable from database and it retrievers all data asked for except the image. here is the code

```
 dt = new DataTable();
        dt = dbClass.ConnectDataBaseReturnDT(usr, ID);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {


            LabelLastLogin.Text = dt.Rows[0]["LastLogin"].ToString();
            lblCreated.Text = dt.Rows[0]["RegisterDate"].ToString();
            UserName.Text = dt.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();

            byte[] barrImg = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["UserPicture"];
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(barrImg);
            UserImage.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
```

asp code

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="SkyBlueBorder" valign="top" width="18%">
                            <asp:Image ID="UserImage" runat="server" Width="140px" />


                            <br />
                            <span class="SmallBlackText">Name:</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="UserName" 
                                runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <span class="SmallBlackText">Join On:</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblCreated" 
                                runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <span class="SmallBlackText">Last Login</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="LabelLastLogin" 
                                runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Am I doing it wrong and what is the best solution please!

thanks

Comment: Can you post asp code as well ?

Comment: I edited the code above and added your request.

Comment: there was no error at all.

Comment: Inspect the element and see what you get for the image tag as data ?

Comment: How are you storing the image in the database?

Comment: I ran your code on my laptop and it is fine. I am storing images in an Oracle database in a BLOB column.

Comment: I used this function to store it into the database.

byte[] userpicture = new byte[FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length];
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(userpicture, 0, userpicture.Length);

Comment: BTY I'm using sqlserver as a database.

Comment: still couldn't find any solution for me :(.